# Crystal lang: call macro in macro?

Tags: crystal-lang

I wonder a way to call a macro in another macro.

Like this:

```
macro parse(str)
  {{ str.split "/" }}
end

macro do_sth(path)
  {% pathes = parse path %}
  {% for file in pathes %}
    p {{file}}
  {% end %}
end

do_sth "aa/bb/cc"
```

The code in `parse` may be really complicated.

The example code fails to compile with message `undefined macro method: 'parse'`.

Answer (score 2):

As Vlad Faust said,  it's may still not possible. Finally, I adopt some trick like Jonne Haß.

```
macro macro_return(*vals, &block)
  \{% begin %}
  \{%
  {% for arg, ind in block.args %}
    {{arg}} = {{vals[ind]}}
  {% end %}
  %}
  {{ block.body }}
  \{% end %}
end

macro parse(str, &block)
  macro_return {{ str.split "/" }} {{block}}
end

macro do_sth(path)
  parse({{path}}) do |pathes|
    \{% for a in pathes %}
      p \{{a}}
    \{% end %}
  end
end

do_sth "aa/bb/cc"
```

Hoping the native support.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible right now. You should not put a macro call inside another macro. If you really need to extract a compile-time functionality in an outer call, I'd suggest you to experiment with [run](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.27.0/Crystal/Macros.html#run%28filename%2C%2Aargs%29%3AMacroId-instance-method) - it puts the raw output right into the code.

Comment: However sometimes you can still clean up your code by flipping your mindset around: Rather than going from the general to the specific, put the specific around the general. Taking the question's example: https://carc.in/#/r/5okn To dry up you can consider generating many macros in a macro for loop like so: https://carc.in/#/r/5oko or have a macro that defines another macro like so: https://carc.in/#/r/5okp

Comment: @JonneHaß yeah... flip my mindset around. Maybe one day, one creates a new `better_macro` keywords based on macro to support this.